# Does disposing of container remove all registered listeners?

Tags: java, swing, listener, containers, dispose

By invoking [`Window.dispose`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29), are all registered listeners (e.g. action listeners, component listeners, and etc.) removed from the container and its subcomponents?

> Releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its
>   subcomponents, and all of its owned children. That is, the resources
>   for these Components will be destroyed, any memory they consume will
>   be returned to the OS, and they will be marked as undisplayable.

Does this include listeners? If not, is it best practice to explicitly remove listeners prior to or shortly after disposing of the container?

Comment: as long you don't reference any of its subcomponents from other objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does include the listeners

[Quoting](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=354574&seqNum=3):

> Generally speaking, removing listeners is unnecessary. Listeners are
>   garbage collected when a control is disposed of, provided that there
>   are no other references to the listener in the application program.

**PS:** Although this link talks about SWT, it is a general statement appliable to all java.

Comment: @mKorbel your comment on the question itself is in the quoted text **"provided that there are no other references to the listener in the application program."**